# Regex to match a pattern and extract field after :

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the value of a column based on a pattern.

```
Text = {"key1":value1,"key2":value2,"366-Pat?":Complete}
```

```
i.e, (?i)"[^"]* Pat\b[^"] -> matches "366-Pat?"
```

I'm trying to get the value "Complete"

```
**Expected result**: Complete
```

Comment: There is [no match](https://regex101.com/r/Uv55fv/1). Please explain where you are using the regex and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few characters to match until you get to Complete, and there is a `-` before Pat in the example string.

You could use a capture group and allow/disallow the characters for the value that you want:

```
(?i)"[^"]*\bPat\b[^"]*":([^"{}]+)
```

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
- `"[^"]*` Match " and then optionally any char except "
- `\bPat\b` Match the word Pat between word boundaries
- `[^"]*"` Optionally match any char except " and then match the closing "
- `(:[^"{}]+)` Capture **group 1**, match `:` followed by any char except what should not be allowed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YAtKJe/1)